# Quasi-geodesic rays are closed to geodesic rays in proper hyperbolic geodesic spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, geodesic, geometric-group-theory, hausdorff-distance, hyperbolic-groups

We define the boundary of a hyperbolic metric space $\partial X$ as the equivalence classes of geodesic rays up to finite Hausdorff distance and $\partial_q X$ as the equivalence classes of quasi-geodesic rays up to finite Hausdorff. To show that $\partial X\to \partial_q X$ is surjective (in fact bijective) in any proper hyperbolic geodeisc space $X$, it suffices to show that quasi-geodeisc rays are closed to geodesic rays in $X$.

It follows from [Bridson-Haefliger III.H.3.10](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/bridsonhaefligerx.pdf) that let $p\in X$ and $c:[0,\infty)\to X$ a quasi-geodesic ray in $X$. We define $c_n$ to be the sequence of geodesics connecting $p$ and $c(n)$. Apply Arzela-Ascoli by properness of $X$, we have a subsequence $c_{n_i}$ converges to a geodesic ray $c_{\infty}$ and we conclude by stability of quasi-geodesics. My question is how properness of $X$ implies the hypothesis of Arzela-Ascoli i.e. $c_n$ is equicontinuous and bounded. It's clear for geodesics but not geodesic rays for me since the domain is infinite.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The sequence $(c_n)$ is not bounded, but it is equicontinuos (since each $c_n$ is an isometric embedding). You have to work more in order to apply AA theorem.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for your response. Yes, it is equicontinuous since $d(c_n(t),c_n(t'))=|t-t'|$ for any isometric embedding $c_n$! Now, to apply AA we'd like restrict codomain to a compact metric space. If it's some segments, then it's clear but how about geodesic rays?

Comment: Use a diagonal subsequence argument to handle rays.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That makes sense! Pick countable dense subset $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ of $[0,\infty)$, then $c_n(x_1)$ will be in the closed ball of radius $x_1$ that is compact for all $n$. The diagonal subsequence argument has no trouble to continue. So the conclusion of AA still holds. Does that seem correct?

Comment: It does not need to be dense. You can use $x_m=m$ and for each $m$ take the restriction $c_{n,m}$  of $c_n$ to $[0,m]$. Then for each $m$ you get a bounded equicontinuous sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!